# defining an already exisiting numpy array within a class

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy

I am creating an object in python. I have a numpy array from an H5 file that I would like to define within it. The numpy array is `coordinates`. I was poking around online and found tons of information about creating numpy arrays, or creating objects in numpy arrays.. but I can't find anything on defining an already made numpy array inside an object.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, globalIndex, coordinates):

        #Useful things to record
        self.globalIndex = globalIndex
        self.coordinates = numpy.coordinates

        #Dictionaries to be used
        self.localIndices ={}
        self.GhostLayer = {}
```

My question: is there a specific way to define my numpy array within this class? If not (the fact that I couldn't find anything about it makes me think that it can't be done), how else could I import a numpy array?

Comment: Why are you using `numpy.coordinates`? just use `coordinates`.

Comment: Will that recognize a numpy array? I assumed there needed to be some way to denote a numpy array.

Comment: Python is a dynamic typed language, variable names don't have to know anything about the objects they point to, so as long as `coordinates` is a numpy array, then that's what your new variable would be.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and patience. I appreciate it. I wish I could have given you points for your answer.

Comment: No problem, you should also learn about Namespaces or variable scopes in Python.

Comment: Will do. So much to learn; thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, globalIndex, coordinates):

        #Useful things to record
        self.globalIndex = globalIndex
        self.coordinates = coordinates # now self.coordinates is just another name for your array
```

Assuming `n = Node(some_index, numpy_coordinate_array_name)`

Comment: Thank you for the annotations and answer!